# Trouble with error while evaluating nil in if-statement in js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, null

I have an index.js.erb file in Rails 3.0.10 which is like this:

```
$('.loading').hide()
if ("<%= @id %>" && "<%= @session %>") {
  alert("<%= @id %> <%= @session[:open] %>")
}
```

The relevant part of the controller is like this:

```
if @element != "chkbx"
  @session[:open] = !@session[:open]
else
  @session = nil
end

@id = params[:id]
```

When `@element != "chkbx"`, everything works fine, but otherwise I get this error:

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
    You might have expected an instance of Array.
    The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]):
        1: $('.loading').hide()
        2: if ("<%= @id %>" && "<%= @session %>") {
        3:  alert("<%= @id %> <%= @session[:open] %>")
        4: }
        5: 
        6: 
        app/views/search/index.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_search_index_js_erb___1015507201_70338196455640_0'
        app/controllers/search_controller.rb:32:in `index'
```

Isn't this very strange? Shouldn't the if in the js.erb stop executing when it finds that `@session` is `nil`? I have also tried with `@session = false` in the controller.

I have a similar problem when I have commented out code in a js.erb-file with `//` at the beginning of the code line. The code is still evaluated and generates errors.

Is there something I haven't understood about js.erb-files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, ERB has to render the ERB code into JS code so that expression in the `if` block is being evaluated by ERB during rendering (otherwise it wouldn't be able to render the code into JS).

Now, if you had ONLY the JS code like this:

```
$('.loading').hide()
if (id && session) {
  alert(something);
}
```

Then yes, something would be strange about it evaluating anything in the `if` block because it should fail on `session`.

I would just rewrite your code a little bit:

```
$('.loading').hide()
if ("<%= @id %>" && "<%= @session %>") {
    <% if @session %>
        alert("<%= @id %> <%= @session[:open] %>")        
    <% end %>
}
```

By the way, commented out code still has to be evaluated by ERB during rendering as well.  So if you're going to comment it out in the `.js.erb` file then you need to comment it out using ERB's syntax, not Javascript's.

```
<% 
=begin %>
  $('.loading').hide()
  if ("<%= @id %>" && "<%= @session %>") {
      <% if @session %>
          alert("<%= @id %> <%= @session[:open] %>")        
      <% end %>
  }
<% 
=end %>
```

Or for single lines of code:

```
<%# your_ruby_code_goes_here %>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! That was very understandable! Now it's working. :-) Had to remove = from '<%= if' and '<%= end' though.

Comment: Yeah sorry I use HAML so I'm not very good with ERB syntax :)